# Replace PHP code in Wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I'm trying to add a last item to the wordpress primary menu. So here is my question:

I have a code in functions.php that works well:

```
function add_last_nav_item($items) {
  return $items .= '<li><a href="#" >Contact</a></li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
```

I need to replace which is inside the `<li>` tags with this:

```
<li><?php if(function_exists(wp_forecast)) { wp_forecast( wp_forecast("A") ); } ?></li>
```

I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function add_last_nav_item($items) {
    ob_start();

    echo '<li>';

    if (function_exists('wp_forecast')) { 
        wp_forecast( wp_forecast("A") );
    }

    echo '</li>';

    $end = ob_get_clean();
    $items = $items . $end;
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
```

Comment: Thank you Stanimir! It worked. But i still have an issue there. The menu where i want to insert the code shrinks and moves with animation when scroll down. The code works because the wp-forecast plugin appears in the front end, but it doesnt stick to the menu. It stays always in the same place. Perhaps you know what should i do?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a link to your site please?
This seems like CSS issue and I am not sure how it looks, so if you can to provide a link it will be very helpful

Comment: Of course my friend. <www.cabalegria.com.ar/yvate/>. You will see the last item is out of the menu container. Maybe i should modify some other files of the theme. I know it is difficult for you without accessing all the files, but with any advice you can give me I will be very pleased.

Comment: Hey, can you please clarify what the code is supposed to do?
I thought it should add additional element at the end of the menu. Do you want to replace the html in all li elements?

Regards,
Stanimir

Comment: Stanimir: as you can see at the end of the menu there is a number like this 12º C on the right. You can see it is outside the menu. It is a real time weather plugin called wp-forecast. I want to have that plugin behave like a menu item, so every time the user scrolls the page, that weather number stays at the same level of the menu items.

Comment: Hey, I have spent some time on this, and it seems that the problem is the code that equalize the height of elements.
The problem is that the code in avia.js calculates the `a` elements that is in the `li` element. For some reason the forecast code is outside that `a` and it's hight is calculated differently.

Without access I am not able to help, because I need to change more than one file, and I need to test that everything is ok.

I am not sure that it's allowed to require access to your server, but if it is I  will be glad to help you with this.

Comment: Stanimir! Im sorry for my lately answer. I really really appreaciate all your help. Thing is the client finally dont want the temperature in the menu right now. If you dont care, i will ask for your help if they change their mind. Thanks!!

Comment: Hahah, don't worry my friend, the client is always right :)
Wishing you all the best with the project.